# convert element of list to int in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a function, and I need to specify what happens if the list has only 1 element. I want the function to return the element, but I don't know how to convert the element to an `Int`. Any help? I've tried `round`, `frominteger`, `realtofrac`, but nothing worked.

```
pMaiore :: Ord a => [a] -> Int

pMaiore [x]=                                      --give x but converted to Int
pMaiore (x:xs:xss)= if x>=xs then pMaiore(x:xss)
                    else  pMaiore(x:xss)          --when x<xs
```

Comment: How can you convert an arbitrary `Ord a` to `Int`?  Are you looking for indices instead of elements?

Comment: What would `pMaiore [("Hello",True)]` return? You probably are using a too general type if you need an `Int` back.

Comment: the objective of the function is to form a list of numbers to say the number of the position of the biggest number , i dont get what u mean with indices , btw i need to keep with the type has is a part of an exercise

Comment: By "indices" Davis is meaning what you called "the number of the position". The point is, you actually do not want to convert `x` to anything -- you want the position of `x` to be returned. For that, you have to remember the original position of `x`. A common trick here is to pre-process the list so that instead of `[x1,x2,x3...]` we work on `[(x1,1),(x2,2),(x3,3),...]`. After this preprocessing, each element is paired with the original position, so the task is easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find max element and index of a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550458/find-max-element-and-index-of-a-list-in-haskell)

Comment: Sorry, but that can't be done. All you know about "a" is that it is an instance of "Ord". You need it to be an instance of Num as well if you want to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
pMaiore :: (Ord a, Integral a) => [a] -> Int

pMaiore [x]= fromIntegral x              --give x but converted to Int
pMaiore (x:xs:xss)= if x>=xs then pMaiore(x:xss)
                    else  pMaiore(x:xss)          --when x<xs
```

If you want to convert an `a` into an `Int` you have to have some connection between them. One way is to use a typeclass. If you know that `a` is going to be a floating point then you can use `RealFrac` instead, and then the `round` function will work.